# How to send variable between functions

Tags: php, mysql

I am a novice in php, so my question will be probably stupid, but I really don't know what to do.

I've created a class, named funkce{}, where I have all of my functions of my web. This php file is called funkce.php
Then I created second php file, which is called index.php, where I call these functions by variable $funkce = new funkce ();

And my problem is:
In function.php I have function "vloz_prvni" for inserting a new user and some details about accomedation. In table about accomedation (name is pronajem_pokoj_nabizim) is foreign key id_user from table "uzivatel" which I get by function mysql_insert_id().

Then I have next function, where I have details about location of the accomedation (the name is "vloz_druhou"). And it's the same as previous table, in table about location (name- "lokalita_nabizim") I have a foreign key from table accomedation, which is id_accomedation and I need to get this value of the foreign key, but I don't know how to pass a variable from previous function.

Code:

```
{
    var $id_uzivatel, $jmeno, $prijmeni, $email, $heslo, $telefon;
    var $kraj, $mesto, $ctvrt, $ulice;
    var $datum_volne, $cena, $hledana_osoba_muz, $hledana_osoba_zena, $hledana_osoba_par, $pocet_hledanych_osob, $pocet_stavajicich_osob, $popis;


    public function vloz_prvni ($jmeno, $prijmeni, $email, $heslo, $telefon, $datum_volne, $cena, $hledana_osoba_muz, $hledana_osoba_zena, $hledana_osoba_par, $pocet_hledanych_osob, $pocet_stavajicich_osob, $popis)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO uzivatel (jmeno, prijmeni, email, heslo, telefon) VALUES     ('$jmeno', '$prijmeni', '$email', '$heslo', '$telefon')");

        $vysledek=mysql_query("SELECT id_uzivatel FROM uzivatel WHERE email='$email'");
        $zkouska= MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysledek);
        $id_uzivatel=$zkouska['id_uzivatel'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO inzerat_nabizim (id_uzivatel, datum_vlozeni) VALUES ('$id_uzivatel', CURRENT_DATE)");
        $id_inzerat_nabizim = mysql_insert_id();
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO pronajem_pokoj_nabizim (id_inzerat_nabizim, datum_volne, cena, hledana_osoba_muz, hledana_osoba_zena, hledana_osoba_par, pocet_hledanych_osob, pocet_stavajicich_osob, popis)
    VALUES ('$id_inzerat_nabizim', '$datum_volne', '$cena', '$hledana_osoba_muz', '$hledana_osoba_zena', '$hledana_osoba_par', '$pocet_hledanych_osob', '$pocet_stavajicich_osob', '$popis')");


    global $id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim;
    $id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = mysql_insert_id();

    }
    function vloz_druhou ($kraj, $mesto, $ctvrt, $ulice)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO lokalita_nabizim (id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim, kraj, mesto, ctvrt, ulice) VALUES ('$id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim','$kraj', '$mesto', '$ctvrt', '$ulice')");
    }
}
?>
```

And I need to get the variable $id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim from function "vloz_prvni" to function "vloz_druhou".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `I've created a class, named function{}` yeah, how could that possibly go wrong? :)

Comment: Are you working with some documentation? Could you provide link on it?

Comment: To further explain the comment of @rinukkusu: `function` is a keyword and cannot be used as class name.

Comment: No, I don't have any documentaion.

Comment: The name of my class isn't function, I'm not native english speaker so I just translated my "funkce" to english - "function". So the name of my class is "funkce".

Comment: @user3815206 , why are you have started to use mysql_* functions? Where did you find mentioning of it?

Comment: i was just looking for solution through the internet and found some. What is wrong about them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is not so clear

(1) A class name cannot be a reserved word. So i guess its not function.
(2) If you want to use a value from variable in another function then declare that variable as global
Example

```
    <?php
      function sum()
      {
        $a=1;
        $b=2;
        return $a+$b;
       }
      global $x;
      $x=sum();
      $n="this is final";
      function display($n)
      {
        global $x;
        echo "$n"." $x";
       }
      display($n);
    ?>
```

Comment: I need this:
global `$id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim = mysql_insert_id();`

but this script isn't correct, it expects semicolon right after the equal sign.

And I need this:

`function a {
$id=mysql_insert_id();
}

function b {
mysql_query = "INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES ('$id')"
}`

I need to send the variable $id to another function.

Comment: ok that my mistake. I have edited the code so take a look again. And if function you are calling is returning more then 1 value then use it as array. ex global $x; $x[]= mysql_insert_id();

Comment: and if its array then i think while inserting you will need to use for loop as $id[0]. Hope you got it.

Comment: It's still not working. 

Notice: Undefined variable: id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim

Comment: Ok i don't know i got it correctly or not because of language used. But i don't understand that why don't you call  mysql_insert_id() inside vloz_druhou($kraj, $mesto, $ctvrt, $ulice).

Comment: Ok this one is last and **Solution** for it. For using value of global variable you need to again use global keyword. Have a look at an small example i created. Let us know if it helps

Comment: Im sorry, but I dont understand to your code. But I realized this wouldn't be useful even if it works. So screw it. Thank you very much anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint - Use global array.

Please note the changes, this should work fine -

```
{
    var $id_uzivatel, $jmeno, $prijmeni, $email, $heslo, $telefon;
    var $kraj, $mesto, $ctvrt, $ulice;
    var $datum_volne, $cena, $hledana_osoba_muz, $hledana_osoba_zena, $hledana_osoba_par, $pocet_hledanych_osob, $pocet_stavajicich_osob, $popis;
    var $id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim;

    public function vloz_prvni ($jmeno, $prijmeni, $email, $heslo, $telefon, $datum_volne, $cena, $hledana_osoba_muz, $hledana_osoba_zena, $hledana_osoba_par, $pocet_hledanych_osob, $pocet_stavajicich_osob, $popis)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO uzivatel (jmeno, prijmeni, email, heslo, telefon) VALUES     ('$jmeno', '$prijmeni', '$email', '$heslo', '$telefon')");

        $vysledek=mysql_query("SELECT id_uzivatel FROM uzivatel WHERE email='$email'");
        $zkouska= MySQL_Fetch_Array($vysledek);
        $id_uzivatel=$zkouska['id_uzivatel'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO inzerat_nabizim (id_uzivatel, datum_vlozeni) VALUES ('$id_uzivatel', CURRENT_DATE)");
        $id_inzerat_nabizim = mysql_insert_id();
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO pronajem_pokoj_nabizim (id_inzerat_nabizim, datum_volne, cena, hledana_osoba_muz, hledana_osoba_zena, hledana_osoba_par, pocet_hledanych_osob, pocet_stavajicich_osob, popis)
    VALUES ('$id_inzerat_nabizim', '$datum_volne', '$cena', '$hledana_osoba_muz', '$hledana_osoba_zena', '$hledana_osoba_par', '$pocet_hledanych_osob', '$pocet_stavajicich_osob', '$popis')");
        $GLOBALS['id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim'] = mysql_insert_id();
    }
    function vloz_druhou ($kraj, $mesto, $ctvrt, $ulice)
    {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO lokalita_nabizim (id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim, kraj, mesto, ctvrt, ulice) VALUES ('".$GLOBALS['id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim']."','$kraj', '$mesto', '$ctvrt', '$ulice')");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, it's not working, because it dosn't know that id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim in that array in the function.

Notice: Undefined index: id_pronajem_pokoj_nabizim

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php
have a look at this page's example..

Comment: It should work, I think there's some problem with commas, but I don't know how to fix it. When I use the code you wrote, it's not working because the SQL code is closed by " right before .$GLOBALS.